# None of the samples of accord.net handles international parsing of decimals

Tags: accord.net

Since all the input sample files for the programming samples of accord.net are using en-US decimal points, all regions that are not using that decimal point will not be able to load the sample files, because the parsing of the decimalnumbers fails.

Here is the fix:
before the load loop add this line:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo us = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Then parse the decimals like this:

```
double.Parse(strs[0], us.NumberFormat);
```

Comment: I think this question isn't a good fit for Stackoverflow... I suppose a better place would be Accord.NET's issue tracker at https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is not a question, but a bug-report